# Making Two Materialize Switches of Different Colors

Tags: javascript, css, materialize

I was able to make a single materialize switch and it looks great, but now I want a second switch - with a different color setup than my first one. This is the code I *want* to run, but my switches just disappear when I try to change the class name!! Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

HTML:

```
  <div class="switch-1" align="center">
    <label>
      1 OFF
      <input id="Switch1" type="checkbox">
      <span class="lever"></span>
      1 ON
    </label>
  </div>

 <div class="switch-2" align="center">
    <label>
      2 OFF
      <input id="Switch2" type="checkbox">
      <span class="lever"></span>
      2 ON
    </label>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.switch-1 label .lever {
   background-color: #79ff4d;
}
.switch-1 label input[type=checkbox]:checked+.lever {
   background-color: #ff6666;
}
.switch-1 label input[type=checkbox]:checked+.lever:after {
   background-color: #ff3300;
}
.switch-2 label .lever {
   background-color: #79ff4d;
}
.switch-2 label input[type=checkbox]:checked+.lever {
   background-color: #a6a6a6;
}
.switch-2 label input[type=checkbox]:checked+.lever:after {
   background-color: #737373;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  <div class="switch red" align="center">
    <label>
      1 OFF
      <input id="Switch1" type="checkbox">
      <span class="lever"></span>
      1 ON
    </label>
  </div>

   <div class="switch grey" align="center">
    <label>
      2 OFF
      <input id="Switch2" type="checkbox">
      <span class="lever"></span>
      2 ON
    </label>
  </div>
```

with this CSS:

```
.switch.red label .lever {
   background-color: #79ff4d;
}
.switch.red label input[type=checkbox]:checked+.lever {
   background-color: #ff6666;
}
.switch.red label input[type=checkbox]:checked+.lever:after {
   background-color: #ff3300;
}
.switch.grey label .lever {
   background-color: #79ff4d;
}
.switch.grey label input[type=checkbox]:checked+.lever {
   background-color: #a6a6a6;
}
.switch.grey label input[type=checkbox]:checked+.lever:after {
   background-color: #737373;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`switch` is the class that materialize uses to set the aspect of the element, use another class and leave the `switch` class too.

```
<div class="switch switch-1" align="center">
    <label>
        1 OFF
        <input id="Switch1" type="checkbox">
        <span class="lever"></span>
        1 ON
    </label>
</div>

<div class="switch switch-2" align="center">
    <label>
        2 OFF
        <input id="Switch2" type="checkbox">
        <span class="lever"></span>
        2 ON
    </label>
</div>
```